# Selecting a series of check-boxes using combination of tab and enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have a series of check-boxes for which I have been using mouse to check / uncheck. But to make the task quicker, I had thought using the combination of `enter` key to select and `tab` key to move from one element to another. When I use the following code, it works fine but only for `chrome` and doesn't work in `firefox`.

In `firefox` after the first checkbox is checked, focus doesn't shift to the next checkbox in series on pressing the tab key. What could be the reason for it?

Is the following snippet correct?

```
$(':checkbox').keypress(function(event) { // Use enter key to check the checkbox
                            event.preventDefault();
                           if(event.keyCode == 13) { //DETECT ENTER KEY
                               $(this).prop("checked",true);
                           } 
                       });
```

Comment: Did you try adding a tabindex to the checkboxes ?

Comment: @adeneo No. I didn't add `tabindex`. But it works fine for chrome!

Comment: i don't think you need JS at all to do what you describe.